# How to effectively develop plain Html/Javascript project?

Tags: javascript

For the plain Html/Javascript project such as elasticsearch/kibana project (https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana). In order to deploy the project, a developer and run command **grunt build** to generate a **dist** folder which including all Html/Javascript/Css and can be deployed to Tomcat.

But if the project is under development stage, for example, after updating a JavaScript/Html/Css file, it is time-consuming to re-run **grunt build** to generate a **dist** and redeployed to Tomcat. My question is how to develop the project effectively to check the updated JavaScript/Html/Css file in browser. Thanks.

In my case, it is not limited to the Tomcat during the develop/debug process, just take Tomcat as an example. Is there a development mode can accelerate the develop and debug process?

Comment: Are you forced to use Tomcat? Is it possible to switch to another (less pretentious) web server?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Any web container is acceptable.

Comment: Check out this for example(Specially the part about 'watch'): http://blog.elenakolevska.com/using-grunt-with-laravel-and-bootstrap/